# Can `git-p4 sync` grab files only up to the timestamp specified like `p4 sync` does?

Tags: git-p4

I need to import 500+ projects from Perforce to Git, and all are related to each other. For that I need to "freeze" the world and import all the projects from the same time. The script I wrote runs for about 2 days, which means that developers, over those 2 days, could submit changes, which will break the already-imported projects.

I know that `p4 sync //depot/path/to/project/...@$timestamp` imports projects with commits/submissions up to the $timestamp. does `git p4 sync //path/to/projects` have that option? Documentation does not mention import at timestamp at all.

Comment: Did you consider Git Fusion instead?

Comment: I did, good advice, our servers did not support it until last week, I have already written and tested the import script with git-p4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4 suggests that you can do:

```
"//depot/my/project@1,6"
```

This requires calculation of the correct commits, but p4 should be able to give you that.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a good way to do that. You can run `p4 changes //depot/project/...@$date` and get a list of changes and compare this number with the overall number of changes. Doing this calculation will help generate the numbers to insert into git p4 line.